# Was there any talk or initiative made to introduce a formal process for suspending or terminating membership from NATO?

Tags: nato

> **But the North Atlantic Treaty regulating NATO does not have an option
> to suspend or even expel members. But there's the possibility to do
> something to the same effect when a member state persistently violates
> the principles contained in the pact—by failing to safeguard the
> freedom of its people, the country's democracy and the rule of law.** In
> that case, NATO members can unanimously decide to stop assisting that
> ally.

https://www.newsweek.com/could-turkey-expelled-nato-over-blocking-finland-sweden-1708532

Was there any talk or initiative made to introduce a formal process for suspending or terminating membership from NATO? The article discuss whether a country like Turkey can be kicked from NATO, and mentions that yes it is possible for a country to be de-facto expelled, but that there's no formal process for doing so, so I was wondering if there was any talk or initiative made to solve that issue.

Comment: If one could be expelled from a defense alliance easily, the trust in the alliance, that it would come to help, would be undermined. That would be a disadvantage of such a mechanism that probably explains why there hasn't been much official talk about it. And Turkey while initially opposing some new members could be "persuaded" somehow and finally agreed with the NATO extension to Finland and Sweden.

Comment: When President Trump was complaining about other NATO countries not contributing enough, he threatened that the US would withdraw from NATO, not that other countries would be expelled. This suggests which is the more feasible action.